# Como obter o conhecimento necessário sobre um domínio?

Tags: ddd, projeto-de-software

Em DDD uma das principais preocupações que precisamos ter é em realmente entender o domínio sendo considerado, ou seja, entender as regras de negócios, os processos e etc. Junto a isso está a construção de uma linguagem ubiqua usada tanto pelo desenvolvedor quanto pelos especialistas de negócio.

É claro que esse conhecimento que precisamos ter sobre o domínio deve vir dos especialistas de domínio, mas como obter esse conhecimento de forma eficiente? Quer dizer, quais são boas estratégias para conseguir os dados necessários por parte dos especialistas de domínio?

Claramente, eu já estou supondo um cenário no qual exista alguem disponível que concorde em cooperar com o desenvolvimento. Acredito que a principal forma de obter esse conhecimento seja com entrevistas, mas chegar no especialista de domínio e falar : "como funciona seu trabalho?" me parece uma pergunta muito ampla, propensa a permitir perda do foco e com chances de não fornecer o conhecimento realmente necessário.

Dessa forma, quais são metodos eficientes para obter as informações realmente necessárias dos especialistas de negócio e como saber quais informações são realmente necessárias?

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua pergunta está mais relacionada com levantamento e análise de requisitos do que com o DDD em si.

O DDD não apresenta nenhuma técnica para o levantamento de requisitos. Ele deixa claro que o conhecimento sobre o domínio é aprofundado ao longo do projeto, mas como fazer?

Uma maneira de fazer isso é utilizando métodos Ágeis:

## Demanda de software sempre parte do cliente

Uma coisa importante que a pergunta parece ignorar é que a demanda por software **sempre** parte de um cliente. **Sempre**, **siempre**, **always**, **forever**, **toujours**, **sempiternum!**

Mas não se preocupe, sua pergunta não é a única a ignorar isso e esta é uma das causas do fracasso dos projetos de software: tentar atender demandas que não sejam exclusivamente as demandas reais do cliente.

Nessa hora você pode começar a questionar:

- *"A Apple, com seus reconhecidos softwares, tem por filosofia que o cliente não sabe o que quer até você dizer para ele".*
- *"O Google introduziu um mecanismo de busca baseado em ranking que ninguém sabia que preciava."*
- *"O dono da minha empresa é um visionário, nós desenvolvemos as idéias da cabeça dele e depois vendemos para clientes que nunca demandaram isso de nós."*
- *"Eu mesmo estou desenvolvendo um software que é idéia minha, nenhum cliente pediu."*

Mas repare que em todos estes casos na verdade **há um cliente**. As demandas estão saindo da cabeça de alguém que sabe o que quer. Cada microesforço só deve ser aplicado no desenvolvimento de software se estiver diretamente relacionado com estas demandas do cliente.

Métodos ágeis como XP e Scrum trazem o cliente para dentro do time e o cliente não está ali apenas para responder perguntas ou porque "concordou em cooperar" - **o cliente destacado para o projeto é um especialista no negócio e está ali para dizer o quê e quando deve ser feito**.

## Atende-se uma demanda de cada vez, e cada demanda é bem pequena

Logo, aprofunda-se o conhecimento de uma pequena parte do domínio de cada vez.

O cliente não decide de uma única vez o que fazer e em que ordem fazer, ele faz este trabalho ao longo de todo o projeto pois o conhecimento dele próprio se aprofunda na medida em que os recursos de software vão sendo entregues.

Ora, se você estiver trabalhando em uma demanda específica, você não precisa perguntar para o cliente "como funciona o seu trabalho" na esperança de ele conseguir te explicar e você conseguir assimilar de uma vez todo o domínio. Ao invés, você perguntará: "como esta tarefa em específico é realizada?", e então desenvolvedor e cliente projetarão um pequeno recurso de software necessário para atender uma pequena demanda.

## Como se transforma a demanda de um produto inteiro em demandas pequenas

O passo-a-passo (bem fácil de entender e bem difícil de aprender a fazer) é:

- Partimos de uma visão do projeto ou do software e também de uma visão do domínio - isso vai produzir de 1 a 3 pequenos documentos. A visão do domínio está prevista no DDD (*"Domain Vision Statement"*).
- Desta visão nascem grandes requisitos. Um nome bacana para um grande requisito é **épico**.
- O épico de maior valor para o cliente é escolhido para ser desenvolvido primeiro.
- Este primeiro épico é dividido em pequenos requisitos. Um nome bacana para estes pequenos requisitos é **histórias do usuário**. Um template bacana para história do usuário é: **eu, no papel de *X*, quero fazer *Y* a fim de ter o resultado *Z***.
- Eventualmente uma história do usuário resultante da divisão do épico ainda é grande demais, então ela também será tratada como épico e será dividida novamente.
- Quando houver algumas histórias do usuário pequenas o bastante, elas são priorizadas.
- Agora, para cada uma das histórias mais prioritárias, é que você pergunta para o cliente: **como esta tarefa em específico é realizada?** Daí podem ser produzidos protótipos em papel (*mockups*) e outros documentos, que são anexados à história.

Depois de estabelecidas as visões, o restante do processo é repetido ao longo de todo o projeto.

## Conclusão

Em **DDD**, o conhecimento macro do domínio é assimilado no começo do projeto através da definição da visão.

No **Desenvolvimento Ágil de Software**, este conhecimento é aprofundado aos poucos ao longo de todo o projeto. Cada pequeno requisito exigirá o aprofundamento de uma pequena parte do domínio, e o estudo de uma parte de cada vez não é amplo nem vago e é menos sujeito à perda de foco.

O **DDD**, apesar de não fornecer técnicas para o aprofundamento do conhecimento no domínio, deixa bastante claro que este conhecimento evolui ao longo do projeto. Os **métodos ágeis** trazem estas técnicas que são requeridas pelo DDD.